# Is staying in Fedora with a 4 gigs system Safe?

Tags: fedora, ram, safety

So I recently switched to Fedora Linux, and At least it eats 1.5 gigs of ram after I installed software, it ate 1.7, and I have a 4 gig system, so is it safe?

I am referring to Memory

Comment: Have you tried the [LXDE](https://spins.fedoraproject.org/en/lxde/) spin?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? Do you have swap space available?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what other programs you want to run.

If you, for example, don't run *any* other programs, the system will be quite happy to use 1.7 out of 4 gigs indefinitely.

2 GB of available memory is not amazing but should suffice for light use.

Comment: Ok, but that is my only computer so, I will switch to another distro.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using Fedora Gnome (which is the default option) . You can also try using the [Xfce](https://spins.fedoraproject.org/en/xfce/) , [LxQt](https://spins.fedoraproject.org/en/lxqt/) , [Cinnamon](https://spins.fedoraproject.org/en/cinnamon/) or [Lxde](https://spins.fedoraproject.org/en/lxde/) editions. All of them are conservative on memory usage. I haven't actually used them but [Lxde](https://lxde.github.io/) Desktop in [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/) just used about 300-400 MBs of memory after booting up in my case . So it might suit your need.